# how to pass int values in mysql query string?

Tags: php, mysql

here my code-

```
$sqlpin = "SELECT pinId FROM tblpin WHERE pinId = '$pin_no', status = 0 ";
```

`status` is `int` type.
it is showing parse error.

Comment: Probably a nice SQL injection on `$pin_no`.

Answer (score 6):

SELECT pinId FROM tblpin WHERE pinId = '$pin_no' **AND** status = 0

Comment: when shoul I use `status = '0'` or `status = "0"`

Comment: it does not matter. quotes are significant for strings, ints can be used with any quotes, or even without them.

Comment: When should you use quotes around numeric values? The answer is NEVER.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
$sqlpin = "SELECT pinId FROM tblpin WHERE pinId = '$pin_no' and status = 0 ";
```

Comment: when shoul I use `status = '0'` or `status = "0"`

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error is caused by comma in `WHERE` clause. You should use `AND` logical operator to connect these two conditions.

btw: If some column has numeric type don't pass values with apostrophes, just: `colName = 123`. Only text values requires apostrophes/quotes (in MySQL both has exactly the same meaning).